# How to add custom OID for subject field on certificates issued by Windows Server 2008 R2 CA?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services, ssl-certificate

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller with Active Directory Certificate Services installed. It's configured as an Enterprise Root CA.

I have configured a custom certificate template so that I can generate extended validation SSL certificates from the CA.

In many of the EV SSL certificates, the following OIDs are specified in the "Subject" field of issued certificates:

2.5.4.15 = ORGANIZATION TYPE
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = STATE
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = COUNTRY

For example:
2.5.4.15 = Private Organization
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Arizona
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US

I'm trying to see if there is already a place for me to specify these custom OIDs and their values to be used when requesting the certificate through Active Directory from my CA.

I took a look at an EV SSL Hotmail certificate, and its certificate has the OIDs above in its Subject field:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yffaz.org](http://yffaz.org/imgs/hotmail.png))</sub>

If I use the MMC certificate snap-in and select "local computer" and attempt to request a certificate using my custom certificate template using supplied values, I only see the following items, and none where I can specify an OID:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yffaz.org](http://yffaz.org/imgs/adcs-request.png))</sub>

Does anyone have an idea of how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The command-line [`certreq` tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx) will allow you to include arbitrary extensions (by OID) in your request but the tool is somewhat less than intuitive to use.